# How to set default columns for "Details" view WITHOUT making "Details" the default view?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

In Windows Explorer "details" view, I would like to set the default columns.

As far as I know, there is a solution for that, but it entails setting "details" as the default view (at least for the type of folder needed). I don't want that.

So, is there a way to set the default columns for "Details" view WITHOUT making "Details" the default view?

Comment: @closevoter If you know the answer, please post it. If you care what your default columns are, maybe others do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the standard *FolderTypes*, Documents, Downloads, Generic, Music, Pictures, and Videos, you can use **Appy to folders**, the "standard" way of customizing folder view templates.

- Open a folder that uses the *FolderType* you want to modify
- Switch to **Details** and select the columns you want
- Switch to your desired default Icon mode
- Execute **Apply to Folders**

[image]

If you want to modify the default columns for **Libraries** or **SearchResults**, that would take some registry editing.

Comment: Note: can also be done in PowerShell